# WebView data caching (Android)

Tags: android, caching, webview

1. I load HTML data into WebView with loadDataWithBaseURL
2. Do it one more time
3. Execute the following code and instead of going back to the 1st 
   page - whole app exits. What am I doing wrong here?

   ```
   public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && this.browser.canGoBack()) {
       this.browser.goBack();
       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   ```

   }

Also - is it possible for WebView cache to survive Activity#onStop? 
Basically - if I close app and reopen - I want WebView to display last 
data that was loaded, currently - I'll get a blank screen and then 
have to reload same data again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that load* does not create a new WebView, nor does it do anything special like create a history record, unfortunately.

You probably want call startActivity() and invoke a second activity for the second set of data.

Comment: My WebView is embedded into single activity, I guess I will have to monkey with history